# Error during the installation of Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have downloaded too many versions of Python.

But during the installation of each of them; it gives me the following error:

> One or more issues caused the setup to fail. 
>   Please fix the issues and then retry setup. 
>   For more information see the log file.

`0x80240017 - Unspecified error`

---

The log file is a notepad file; and I don't know how to attach it to this post.
I have searched the word `error` in that file; and the result as follows:

- [0100:0778][2017-10-18T12:23:17]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.
- [15AC:02D0][2017-10-18T12:23:17]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to configure per-machine MSU package.
- [15AC:02D0][2017-10-18T12:23:17]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.
- [15AC:1558][2017-10-18T12:23:17]e000: Error 0x80070642: Failed attempt to download URL: 'https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/amd64a2/core.msi' to: 'C:\Users\LENOO-PC\AppData\Local\Temp{E5B78068-5C25-4FCD-B784-FEBC797E2FE6}\core_JustForMe'
- [15AC:1558][2017-10-18T12:23:17]e000: Error 0x80070642: Failed to acquire payload from: 'https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/amd64a2/core.msi' to working path: 'C:\Users\LENOO-PC\AppData\Local\Temp{E5B78068-5C25-4FCD-B784-FEBC797E2FE6}\core_JustForMe'
- [15AC:1558][2017-10-18T12:23:17]e313: Failed to acquire payload: core_JustForMe to working path: C:\Users\LENOO-PC\AppData\Local\Temp{E5B78068-5C25-4FCD-B784-FEBC797E2FE6}\core_JustForMe, error: 0x80070642.

Comment: You can use https://pastebin.com/ to share log details. Try to search for the error in the log file, if it is too large, and copy only part that contains the error.

Comment: It seems like the error is related to installing some of the Windows updates/components, that are required by Python. I would suggest the first thing to try to run Python installation under Administrator rights. P.S. you probably should specify the OS that you are installing Python on.

Comment: @GSazheniuk ; I have searched the word 'error' in that file; and I have added some details to the post.

Answer (score 1):

Try install C Runtime update from Microsoft. Use following link,
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows. Then Try to reinstall python 3.5

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem recently. I noticed that the error came when trying to run the python.msi from a remote/network location. Copy the installer to local machine and it should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my fresh installation of windows 8.1(64x). The problem was solved by updating the Windows using Windows Update panel. Following updates were installed(I can not be specific about which of them resolved my issue) but after installation of the updates and a system reboot, the latest version of python(3.10.5) was successfully installed on my machine.

[image]